# PHP: Generate random Code excluding (0, 1, O and L)

Tags: php, algorithm, random

I am trying to generate random voucher code applying the following rules:

Alphanumeric combination 5 characters in capital case (A-Z, 0-9, and take away 1, 0, I, O).

This is my try

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    return substr(str_shuffle("23456789ABCDEFGHIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
}


echo generateRandomString();
?>
```

but i am not sure if there is a better way of doing this

Answer (score 2):

If you need to call this function lots of times, your current implementation will be very slow, because it uses much more calls of random function than it is necessary (if $length < 32). Also if your set of allowed characters is smaller than number of characters in the result, your current implementation will return wrong result too. And also your implementation does not allow repeating of characters in the result, but in the specification it is not forbidden to repeat characters.

A little more accurate solution is to use `array_rand()`:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
  $allowed = str_split('23456789ABCDEFGHIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'); // it is enough to do it once

  $res = '';
  foreach (array_rand($allowed, $length) as $k)
    $res .= $allowed[$k];
  return $res;
}
```

Comment: my try is better because i do not loop

Comment: Yes, your code works without loops. But your code will fail if `$length==50`. And also it is very slow, because `str_shuffle` calls slow `random` function 32 times instead of `$length` times. It will be a problem if you need to generate millions of short random strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
function generateRandom($length = 5) {
    $possibleChars = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    $rndString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $rndString .= $possibleChars[rand(0, strlen($possibleChars) - 1)];
    }
    return $rndString;
}

echo generateRandom();
```

Here you can define the characters which you want to have in your random string.

The problem with your function is that any char will be just used 1 time per call. Its not really random. And the lenght of the random string would also be limited to the amount of characters you have.

For example: AAAAA is not possible with your function, with mine it is.

Comment: my try is better because i do not loop

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string longer than your charset, that method will fail. Please can you try the code below;

```
<?php
    function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
        $chars = "23456789ABCDEFGHIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //Your char-set
        $charArray = str_split($chars); //Your array representation of chars
        $charCount = strlen($chars); //Your char-set length
        $result = "";

        //Loop throught required `$length`
        for($i=1;$i<=$length;$i++)
        {
            $randChar = rand(0,$charCount-1); //Pick a random char in range of our chars
            $result .= $charArray[$randChar]; //Concatenate picked char to result
        }
        return $result;
    }


    echo generateRandomString(75);
?>
```

Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/D1EQ9T
Hope this helps.

Comment: my try is better because i do not loop

Comment: @Dahab this is not a metric for your purpose, if you need a string longer than 32 chars your method will fail + you wont get a string which chars repeating like AA789 or ABB55. Total execution duration of this method is 0.01 - 0.02 sec and still you can imrpove this for concurrent use.